# How many companies are working on creating viable spaceplanes in the near future for human spaceflight(10-20 years)

Tags: future-missions, spaceplane, conceptual, human-rating

As we are goinh into 2019 and we've seen the likes of XCOR Aerospace adn Virgin orbit working towards spaceplanes. How many other companies are working on getting humans to space, suborbital and orbital.

Comment: There are some "spaceplanes" for sub orbital ballistic flights, but is there anything capable of orbital flights?

Comment: I wouldn't call them ballistic , but if I may ask, why do you define them that way.

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_missile) for ballistic missile and [ballistic trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion).

Answer (score 5):

At this point the only company actively working (at least publicly) on creating a "spaceplane" for human spaceflight is Virgin Galactic (Plane actually made by Scaled Composites).  Their SpaceshipTwo is only suborbital, however.

Other companies have spaceplanes in their long term plans - but usually as a goal, rather than a funded strategic path.  For instance, Sierra Nevada Corporation, still hopes to make a human rated [Dreamchaser](https://www.sncorp.com/what-we-do/dream-chaser-space-vehicle/), but at the moment they are focusing on a smaller cargo-only variant. They had originally bid a crewed Dreamchaser for NASA's [commercial crew program](https://www.geekwire.com/2018/paul-allens-stratolaunch-unveils-plans-new-family-rockets-space-plane/), but they were not selected.  Stratolaunch also recently announced their [long term road map](https://www.geekwire.com/2018/paul-allens-stratolaunch-unveils-plans-new-family-rockets-space-plane/), which includes a winged vehicle that would have "a follow up variant for crew".  Some have [speculated](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/239083-air-forces-x-37b-space-plane-become-astronaut-ambulance) that the Boeing X37 could be upgraded to cargo crew.  There are several others who fall into the category of "one day we want to have a spaceplane", but in general it is  very long term dream.  Often from companies that haven flown any vehicles.

Comment: Technically the Dream Chaser and x37 are not spaceplanes in the same way that the shuttle is not a spaceplane; they all launch on conventional rockets, not runways.

Comment: @Dragongeek - I'm not really sure there are any true "space planes" in that case.  Spaceship2 launches under the wings of an airplane.  Same with Bristol.  Sure they have horizontal takeoff from a runway, but only thanks to their first stage being an actual plane.

Answer (score 5):

If "working on" includes "trying to raise money for" then in the UK, Bristol Spaceplanes is still trying:

[image: David Ashford with a model of the sub-orbital Ascender]

And Reaction engines still has long-term plans for a Skylon-like vehicle, capable of carrying a passenger module"

[image: Reaction engines SPLM concept]

Comment: Pretty crazy that we'll get more legroom on a passenger spaceflight than a transatlantic flight-- that passenger shuttle looks decently roomy.

Comment: wait 'til you see the reclined seats @MagicOctopusUrn, but it's cramped compared to the shuttle...

Comment: compared to Soyuz on the other hand, amazing.

Comment: Good call on these two.  I know Bristol and Reaction have been going at it for many, many years.